# Calculate difference between cells in different rows in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe in pandas like this:

```
       Timestamp   ID      X X Diff       Y Y Diff
0              0  100  1.728   None  14.378   None
1             12  100  2.035   None  14.378   None
2             24  100  2.342   None  14.378   None
3             36  100  2.630   None  14.378   None
4             48  100  2.937   None  14.416   None
```

What I want to do is calculate the difference between X and Y values in rows, adding the results into the X Diff and Y Diff respective columns for a result like this.

```
    Timestamp   ID      X X Diff       Y Y Diff
0           0  100  1.728   None  14.378   None
1          12  100  2.035  0.307  14.378      0
2          24  100  2.342  0.307  14.378      0
3          36  100  2.630  0.288  14.378      0
4          48  100  2.937  0.307  14.416  0.038
```

Calculations should only happen when the row and it's predeccessor have the same ID (If predeccessor is empty -first row- or has a different ID default 'None' stays).

I created a function to do this through a basic for loop for all entries belonging to the same ID:

```
def getDifferences(dataframe, column):
    for i in range(19):
        startValue = dataframe.iloc[i][column]
        endValue = dataframe.iloc[i+1][column]
    
        diff = endValue - startValue
        if column == "X":
            dataframe.at[i+1, "X Diff"] = diff
        else:
            dataframe.at[i+1, "Y Diff"] = diff
```

Since the data is cleaned up, and the full dataframe always has 20 entries of the same ID followed by other 20 entries of another ID, I could create a second loop over the whole dataframe, isolating those 20 belonging entries into a new dataframe, use above method and repeat.

However I am led to belive this double for-loop is by far not the most efficient way to do this, considering my dataframe contains over 100k rows in total.

I tried searching the web, but found no inbuilt pandas function to achive a more elegant solution rather than the above brute force.

Perhaps someone on here can help me. Maybe there is a numpy way to do this I cant see?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68352573/copy-values-from-one-column-to-another-column-with-different-rows-based-on-two-c/68353188#68353188) can help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Groupby 'ID' and calculate difference and then assign back to df:

```
df[['X diff','Y Diff']]=df.groupby('ID')[['X','Y']].diff()
```

output of `df`:

```
  Timestamp     ID      X        Y      X diff  Y Diff
0   0           100     1.728   14.378  NaN     NaN
1   12          100     2.035   14.378  0.307   0.000
2   24          100     2.342   14.378  0.307   0.000
3   36          100     2.630   14.378  0.288   0.000
4   48          100     2.937   14.416  0.307   0.038
```