# Pandas ValueError: Columns must be same length as key for now apparent reason

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diff

I have a test dataframe, consisting of a reduced sample size of data with the following properties:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('Data/bookstore_0.txt', sep= ' ', header=None)
dataframe.columns = ['Timestamp', 'ID', 'X', 'Y']
dataframe.insert(4, 'X_Diff', None)
dataframe.insert(5, 'Y_Diff', None)
#dataframe[['X_Diff', 'Y_Diff']] = dataframe.groupby('ID')[['X', 'Y']].diff()
dataframe.fillna(0, inplace=True)
dataframe.describe()

             Timestamp  ID               X  Y                           X_Diff      Y_Diff
count   16100.000000    16100.000000    16100.000000    16100.000000    16100.0     16100.0
mean    6583.729193     404.000000         -2.506816        8.656825    0.0         0.0
std     3546.059991     232.390521         12.020219       10.789998    0.0         0.0
min     0.000000        2.000000          -26.970000      -20.233000    0.0         0.0
25%     3720.000000     203.000000        -12.593000        1.958000    0.0         0.0
50%     6840.000000     404.000000         -4.645000       14.339000    0.0         0.0
75%     9360.000000     605.000000          7.870000       17.123000    0.0         0.0
max     13332.000000    806.000000         26.951000       20.521000    0.0         0.0
```

Applying the commented out method  `dataframe[['X_Diff', 'Y_Diff']] = dataframe.groupby('ID')[['X', 'Y']].diff()` yields the following results:

```
           Timestamp              ID               X                Y         X_Diff          Y_Diff
count   16100.000000    16100.000000    16100.000000    16100.000000    16100.000000    16100.000000
mean    6583.729193     404.000000         -2.506816    8.656825        0.039345        -0.004718
std     3546.059991     232.390521         12.020219    10.789998       0.274080         0.183496
min     0.000000        2.000000          -26.970000   -20.233000      -0.922000        -1.133000
25%     3720.000000     203.000000        -12.593000     1.958000       0.000000        -0.007000
50%     6840.000000     404.000000         -4.645000    14.339000       0.000000         0.000000
75%     9360.000000     605.000000          7.870000    17.123000       0.077000         0.000000
max     13332.000000    806.000000         26.951000    20.521000       1.823000         0.883000
```

Using my full dataset, I get the following:

```
txtfiles = glob.glob('Data/*.txt')
frames = [pd.read_csv(file, sep= ' ', header=None) for file in txtfiles]
ped_data = pd.concat(frames)
ped_data.columns = ['Timestamp', 'ID', 'X', 'Y']
ped_data.insert(4, 'X_Diff', None)
ped_data.insert(5, 'Y_Diff', None)
#ped_data[['X_Diff', 'Y_Diff']] = ped_data.groupby('ID')[['X', 'Y']].diff()
ped_data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

ped_data.describe()

            Timestamp              ID               X               Y     X_Diff      Y_Diff
count   108120.000000   108120.000000   108120.000000   108120.000000   108120.0    108120.0
mean      5949.556049      325.945986       -1.028735       10.648398        0.0         0.0
std       3713.754148      250.269185       14.773480       17.339787        0.0         0.0
min          0.000000        0.000000      -37.029000      -28.242000        0.0         0.0
25%       2676.000000      123.000000      -12.456000       -4.186000        0.0         0.0
50%       5772.000000      276.000000       -1.909000       12.858000        0.0         0.0
75%       9036.000000      479.000000       10.421000       20.983000        0.0         0.0
max      14532.000000    1141.000000        36.632000       63.559000        0.0         0.0
```

Applying the commented out method again, however, results in the following error:

```
ped_data[['X_Diff', 'Y_Diff']] = ped_data.groupby('ID')[['X', 'Y']].diff()
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I have tried researching here on other sources, but haven't really found a solution.

The method itself calculates just fine, as simply running

```
ped_data.groupby('ID')[['X', 'Y']].diff()
```

overwrites the X, Y colums with the correct values however, meaning the error has to occur in the

```
ped_data[['X_Diff', 'Y_Diff']] =
```

assigning part.

I'd be thankful for any help!

EDIT: I have found a workaround in case anyone with a similar problem ever stumbles upon this:

By running the dataframe operations on every frame and bringing them together once finalized I was able to avoid the error

```
pedestrian_data = pd.DataFrame()
txtfiles = glob.glob('Data/*.txt')

for file in txtfiles:
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(file, sep= ' ', header=None)
    dataframe.columns = ['Timestamp', 'ID', 'X', 'Y']
    dataframe.insert(4, 'X_Diff', None)
    dataframe.insert(5, 'Y_Diff', None)
    dataframe[['X_Diff', 'Y_Diff']] = dataframe.groupby('ID')[['X', 'Y']].diff()
    dataframe.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    pedestrian_data = pedestrian_data.append(dataframe)
```

It's most likely slower performance wise as it uses a regular Python for loop instead of letting pandas do the heavy lifting, but at least it runs.

I'll still be waiting to see if someone has an answer, just though this to be post-worthy.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `groupby.transform` instead:

```
ped_data[['X_Diff', 'Y_Diff']] = ped_data.groupby('ID')[['X', 'Y']].transform('diff')
```

Comment: This works as in it doesn't throw an error, however it seems to calculate something different than what I want to/what I do with `dataframe[['X_Diff', 'Y_Diff']] = dataframe.groupby('ID')[['X', 'Y']].diff()`. For reference, here is the original thread where I describe the inital problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68420684/calculate-difference-between-cells-in-different-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe